# How to get args for an ansible module written in bash?

Tags: bash, ansible, ansible-module

I wrote an ansible module is bash. It is working fine, but if want to pass arguments to that module and read them in the bash module how can I do that .. please help

```
- name: get top processes consuming high cpu
  gettopprocesses:
    numberofprocesses: 5
```

In library I have bash script
library/gettopprocesses.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
TPCPU=$(ps aux --sort -%cpu | head -${numberofprocesses}
echo "{\"changed\": false, "\msg\": {"$TPCPU"}}"
exit 0
```

Comment: You mean read module arguments from a module written in bash ?

Comment: Yes, I tried standard arguments in bash.. but in ansible module args we pass argument key and its value.. I want read both

Comment: could you show a sample reproductible...

Comment: Writting modules in bash is not part of the documentation anymore. The modern way is to write your module in python and use the dedicated libraries/modules to get your params. Meanwhile, you can find old doc/tutorials which explain how to proceed. An example [here](https://ansible-tutorial.schoolofdevops.com/custom_modules/#writing-module-with-bash). Basically, your script receives a single parameter containing all the module options. Sourcing that param (i.e. `source $1`) is suppose to create the corresponding variables in your script context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write your bask like this: you have to add source $1 to specify you have args

```
#!/bin/bash
source $1
NUMBERPROC=$numberofprocesses
TPCPU=$(ps aux --sort -%cpu | head -${NUMBERPROC})

printf '{"changed": %s, "msg": "%s", "contents": %s}' "false" "$TPCPU" "contents"
exit 0
```

You could add a test to check if right arg is given:

```
#!/bin/bash
source $1

if [ -z "$numberofprocesses" ]; then
    printf '{"failed": true, "msg": "missing required arguments: numberofprocesses"}'
    exit 1
fi

NUMBERPROC=$numberofprocesses
TPCPU=$(ps aux --sort -%cpu | head -${NUMBERPROC})

printf '{"changed": %s, "msg": "%s", "contents": %s}' "false" "$TPCPU" "contents"
exit 0
```